# RUN NSTimer in Background continuously for an Hour?

Tags: ios, background, nstimer

1. You need to opt into background execution with beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.
2. If you are NOT creating the NSTimer in the main thread, you need to add it to the mainRunLoop manually.

considering the mentioned two points, Is it possible to make NSTimer run continuously beyond (10-15mins). ???

Kindly Help !!!

Comment: I could recommend alternatives though if you explained more about your specific situation.

Comment: Lundsey !!! Our App USP is to share location irrespective of whether location service is on or off in device. We have managed all the cases for location update, terminated, suspended, active. But the location service is off in background or suspended mode, we are not able to update location to server.

Comment: If the location service is off in background or suspended mode, we are not able to manage the location fetch/update from/to server.

Comment: What does that have to do with running your NSTimer in the background?

Comment: This way i will have the full control over the call frequency of location updates.

Comment: Why haven't you turned on the location background mode?

Comment: That we have done. but problem is when location service is off from settings, actually in that scenario we need to make a API call with at regular interval for location update.   Actually through that API call we are requesting the location of the phone from carrier network.